# reset the receipt number once its completed one year

Tags: php, mysql

In my project receipt number is autom increment and completion of one year is 1st april to 31st march of every year. once the year is completed the receipt no should reset to 1. I have been trying from long time but couldnot do it as im beginer. thank you so much in advance ..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `receipt_no` FROM tsurphus");   
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT max(receipt_no)+1 FROM tsurphus");
    $res = mysql_fetch_row($data);
    echo $res[0];
    echo $_POST['$res'];
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show an auto increment, it shows a simple query. Try including the year in the query so you select the max number for the current year. better yet, don't worry about the number and use a proper auto-increment field so every receipt has a unique number instead of one that gets repeated every year

Comment: @Shadow thanks for ur response, could you please share me the code what excatly ur suggesting ...thxxxx

Comment: This is fundamentally flawed. Don't use the auto_increment feature for this kind of thing. And DON'T use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a general problem regarding multi sessions. The way how you read `receipt_no` can result in the situation you get two identical numbers when your site is called almost the same time.

There are some approaches. One would be you create at midnight on every 1st April a new table `tsurphus` where the `receipt_no` is reset to 0. Each insert into this table would generate a definitely unique value - when defined as `Auto Increment`.

But this may not be a suitable solution for you due to lack of information.

**Update as requested in a comment**:

I can only provide you the information how I did it. You have to decide if it is suitable for you. For the project I wrote it was the perfect solution because they needed each financial year a complete empty table.

I ran this command as cron job on each 1st January at midnight. The logic was implemented in that way that there was never a collision with existing `INSERT` commands [I mean that there were never `INSERT` commands while the new table was not created yet]:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tsurphus_2016 LIKE tsurphus_2016;
```

I don't know how your internal convention is regarding the name of the `primary key` but - if it is like mine that the `primary key` has the same name like the table - then you have also to rename the `primary key`:

```
ALTER TABLE tsurphus_2016 CHANGE `tsurphus_2015id` 
                              `tsurphus_2016id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

You would have to run it each 1st of April at midnight.

Comment: ignoring the elephant in the room.

Comment: @AlBundy. you are right. there should be different table for each financial year. Could you please do the coding for the same so i can simply copy and paste here as im beginer in php. thank a lot in advance .

Comment: @Explorer There is not really too much for PHP. You have to determinate the *old* table name [I append the financial year - for example 2016] and then replace it by the new financial year. Check my updated answer.